# add a logo over slider in a wp theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

hi, same this post
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/float-logo-over-slider

i also have the same problem, except that the slider i have is http://themepunch.com/revolution/ - Revolution Slider.

please help me on adding the logo to float over the slider.

I know php and stuff, Im a newbie, so kindly tell me where to go. appreciate your help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add image layer on each slide of your logo

```
Go to Revolution slider => Edit slides => Add layer: image
```

Comment: but the image loads after the slide loads. is there a way the image stays?

Comment: decrease the timing of image loading from the settings

Comment: I'm afraid timing still didn't do it. I want the image to "just be there", is there away to do that?would appreciate if you can help me

Comment: What i would want is for it to just float there